# How to backup questions, answers of Stack Exchange

Tags: backup, stack-exchange

I would like to keep a backup of all the questions asked + all answers provided for each question, answers provided + questions for the answer provided, questions favourited on Stack Exchange in the very, very, highly unlikely case that the servers at Stack Exchange fail. How do I go about doing it beside copying everything into a Word document/WordPress? Are there any software or techniques available that would allow me to do a quick backup?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a Stack Exchange support issue. Such questions should be asked at [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the questions you asked and answers you wrote:

See [What is the easiest way for me to download all my comments across all Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209050/178179) and [What is the easiest way for me to download all my questions+answers across *all* stack overflow sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209317/178179):

Go to [Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209050/178179) and run these [queries](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209317/178179):

```
-- Display all questions+answers of a given user

DECLARE @UserId int = ##UserId##

SELECT Posts.Body
FROM Posts
WHERE Posts.OwnerUserId = @UserId

-- Display all comments of a given user

DECLARE @UserId int = ##UserId##

SELECT Comments.Text
FROM Comments
WHERE Comments.UserId = @UserId
```

The main issue is that it needs to be run for each Stack Exchange website you want to retrieve your comments from, which can be pretty tedious to do.

Comment: How about if i want the answers from others for questions i wrote ??